# Which was the name of this Rurouni Kenshin song?

Tags: theme-song, rurouni-kenshin

I remember the song in the begining of this video was from Rurouni Kenshin. But I can't remember its name. Which is the name of that song?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JsOJJlLd8YY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song in your video is the third ending in the series named 'Heart of Sword'.

You can find it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHcHWz4iEk0)